# Vue-Table add class to selected row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using [vue-table-component](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component) to display a table on my view, which can be filtered and sorted easily. But I came up with a problem here.
I need to identify a row which has been clicked. I tried the implementation from [Issue #100](https://github.com/spatie/vue-table-component/pull/100) but this as not changed anything and has not added a class to the clicked `<tr>` element.

My component looks like:

```
<table-component
:data="this.runs.results"
sort-by="id"
sort-order="asc"
:show-caption=false
v-on:rowClick="rowClicked"
:row-class="highlight"
>
```

And the added methods are doing defined as:

```
highlight(row) {
    if (row.data) return this.highlightedRow === row.data.vueTableComponentInternalRowId ? 'highlight' : '';
    return '';
},
rowClicked(row) {
    this.expand = false;
    this.log = eval('`' + this.runs.results[row.data.id].logFile + '`');
},
```

Does there is a way to add a class to a selected row? Or does I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: the merge request did not get merged. you cannot use it currently

Comment: Oh I missed that out, too bad...